# value assignment in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have two value:starid1,starid2,and a list  called starlist, i want to pick up two object from the starlist that contains id starid1 and starid2,and there is no duplicated id in the list.

this is how i write the code

```
star1,star2=None,None
for x in starlist:
    if x.id == starid1:
        star1 = x
    elif x.id == starid2:
        star2 = x
```

here's another way

```
star1 = [x for x in starlist if x.id==starid1][0]
star2 = [x for x in starlist if x.id==starid2][0]
```

or i can convert it to a dictionary and pick the two objects.but i thought the cost was too high, for i only want to assign two values.

i felt so dumb when i wrote those codes down.i think i just missed the proper way to do it in python. tell me how you know to do it better.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, and an example of the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way is to use a generator:

```
star1 = next(x for x in starlist if x.id==starid1)
star2 = next(x for x in starlist if x.id==starid2)
```

This has an advantage of being lazy thus saving memory and stopping early. In your example, this is basically the same as your first loop with `break` statements added to it:

```
star1,star2=None,None

for x in starlist:
    if x.id == starid1:
       star1 = x
       break

for x in starlist:
    if x.id == starid2:
       star2 = x
       break
```

Do note however, that `next` will raise an exception if there's no such item in the list. If you want to avoid that, add a default value to the call:

```
star1 = next((x for x in starlist if x.id==starid1), None)
```

Comment: Your loop would break after the first star is found, a better check would be `if star1 and star2: break`

Comment: Sorry, using a generator like that is **not** a common way to do it.